# Я получаю код в виде строки и мне нужно его вставить в html чтобы он работал при помощи js

Tags: javascript

я получаю код c json файла паршу его в объект и данные которые я получаю это код в виде строки. как мне сделать чтобы этот код когда я его ставлю в html становился кодом, а не оставался строкой?

```
let p_body_content = document.getElementById("p_body_content");
fetch('./js/json/data.json')
  .then(r => r.json())
  .then(data => p_body_content.prepend(data.header))
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В текущем случае надо использовать [insertAdjacentHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) с указанием позиции `afterbegin`:

```js
let parent = document.querySelector('#parent');

parent.insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", '<div id="parent"><p>1</p><p>2</p><p>3</p></div>');
```

```html
<div id="parent"><p>default</p></div>
```

Про все позиции можно почитать в [доках](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML#position)

А [prepend](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/prepend) на вход принимает элемент с типом [Node](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node), поэтому ничего не получается.